# How to display pictures side by side in a 2x2 grid

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I am trying to get these 4 images, with linked text underneath to display as 2x2. Everything I try ends up messing something up and sending one part AWOL. I have tried tables `<td><tr>`, etc.

This is what I have so far...

```
<br />
<div class="image" style="display:inline-block">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
<div style="display:table-caption;caption-side:bottom;">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
   <center>text for link!!!!!</center>
</a>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
<div style="display:table-caption;caption-side:bottom;">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
   <center>text for link!!!!!</center>
</a>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
<div style="display:table-caption;caption-side:bottom;">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
   <center>text for link!!!!!</center>
</a>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
<div style="display:table-caption;caption-side:bottom;">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
   <center>text for link!!!!!</center>
</a>
```

Comment: You've tagged this with newsletter. Is this going to be in an email or is this an online newsletter where you're just formatting a web page?

Comment: This is an email campaign being sent out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If this is for a newsletter, you absolutely need `<table>`s** to get this working in the popular email clients. [Most email clients do not display HTML/CSS as web browsers do](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/) and `<table>`s get the best coverage among email clients.

Here is some basic code that displays a 2x2 grid **safely** in all email clients.

```
<br />
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
            <br />
            <a href="http://www.example.com">text for link!!!!!</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
            <br />
            <a href="http://www.example.com">text for link!!!!!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
            <br />
            <a href="http://www.example.com">text for link!!!!!</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
            <br />
            <a href="http://www.example.com">text for link!!!!!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any tables. Try the code below:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  width: 50%;
}

.image-wrapper:nth-child(even)
{
  padding-left:5px;
}

.image-wrapper:nth-child(odd)
{
  padding-right:5px;
}

.image-wrapper > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
  <span>Caption</span>
</div>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
  <span>Caption 2</span>
</div>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
  <span>Caption 3</span>
</div>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
  <span>Caption 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is giving me the caption to the right of the image, rather than under. Also only 1 image, not 2x2. Also, I need the caption to be linked to a webpage - where can I add that in?

Comment: @Emily127 That's because you haven't added the stylesheet properly (first box in my answer). What newsletter tool are you using?

Comment: This example will work on the web, but not most email clients. Email clients will have trouble with the following: || `<div>`s || `:nth-child` selector || `box-sizing` || `float` (seriously!)